# General techniques for creating complex animations

Tags: graphics, animation, visualization, guidelines

I love good animations of abstract concepts, and when I try to create them myself, I prefer doing so in code to make sure they are exact (and because some things are just way too fiddly to do by hand). In general, Mathematica seems like a nice tool for this, because of its powerful plotting capabilities. My problem is that this tends to get quite annoying once my animation consists of multiple "phases", which cannot all be easily described by a single continuous function.

To give you an idea of what I mean, here are some examples from [a very popular question over on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/733754/50421):

[image]
<sup>[Source](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/744224/50421)</sup>

[image]
<sup>[Source](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/744196/50421)</sup>

Note that I'm specifically *not* talking about animations like the one in the top-voted answer, which can easily be expressed as a large number of graphics primitives whose parameters are continuous functions of some time parameter `t`.

In the two examples above there are lots of different steps to the animation. Objects appear, disappear or undergo qualitatively different motions over their lifetime (like growing, bending, rotating, translating). I find setting up these animations quite cumbersome (to the extent that when I do manage it, I can no longer be bothered to improve the timing of the animation of add ease-in/out effects to the motions). I usually take some approach with creating fiddly `Piecewise` functions of bunches of `If` or `Which` statements. Whatever I do, it's very ad hoc.

As an example, I've tried to recreate the second GIF above. I didn't even bother with the red flashing and a particularly nice presentation, but all movements are there:

```
Table[Graphics[{
   Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}],
   Line[{{1, -.1}, {1, .1}}],
   Text[1, {1, -.2}],
   If[t > 0.5, {
     Line[{{1, 0}, {2, 0}}],
     Line[{{2, -.1}, {2, .1}}],
     Text[2, {2, -.2}]
     }, {}],
   If[t > 1, {
     Line[{{0, 0}, ReIm@Exp[I*Min[1, t - 1] Pi/2]}]
     }, {}],
   If[t > 2, {
     Text[1, {-.1, .5}],
     Arrow[{{-.1, 0.35}, {-.1, 0}}],
     Arrow[{{-.1, 0.65}, {-.1, 1}}],
     Line[{{.5, -.1}, {.5, .1}}],
     Text["1/2", {.5, -.2}],
     Line[{{1.5, -.1}, {1.5, .1}}],
     Text["3/2", {1.5, -.2}]
     }, {}],
   If[2 < t <= 3.5, {
     Red,
     Line[{{.5, 0}, {.5, 0} + ({0, 1} - {.5, 0}) Min[1, t - 2]}]
     }, {}],
   If[t > 3.5, {
     Red,
     Line[{{.5, 0}, {.5, 0} + 
        Sqrt@5/2*ReIm@Exp[I*(Pi - ArcTan@2) (1 - Min[1, t - 3.5])]}]
     }, {}],
   If[t > 4.5, {
     Arrow[{{GoldenRatio, 0.35}, {GoldenRatio, 0.05}}],
     Text["\[Phi] \[TildeTilde] 1.1618", {GoldenRatio, 0.5}]
     }, {}]
   },
  PlotRange -> {{-0.25, 2.25}, {-0.25, 1.25}}], {t, 0, 5.5, 0.04}]
```

This creates a list of frames which you can then stuff into `ListAnimate` or `Export`. Here is the result:

[image]

My main problems are:

- The cumbersome structure of defining hardcoded time ranges. If I decide I want to shorten or lengthen some segment, it will effect the "time codes" of all subsequent animations.
- Repeated things like `Min[1, t - 2]` which I need to get a nice parameter that goes from `0` to `1` at some later time.
- Notice that the growing red line is not the same primitive as the rotating red line, although I guess I could have combined them at the expense of even more unclarity. How can easily apply a series of transformation to the same object over time, in a clear way?
- Not very apparent in this example, but often some transformations work better in certain local coordinate systems (e.g. rotation an object about its centre after the animation has moved it away from the origin). Are there easy ways to compose the animations in such a way that I can always pick the most convenient coordinate system for composing a sequence of transformations?
- In this example, I've got a ton of repeated frames when nothing is happening for half a second. Of course, this could be fixed, and then I could use a custom `DisplayDurations` list for `Export`, but that makes the construction of the frames even more horrible. How can I work around this?
- I haven't even bothered with elements fading in and out like they do in the first example above, because that would add yet another extra transformation (with hardcoded times) for every single object.

All in all, **what are general techniques to make the process of creating such animations with Mathematica more straightforward** with particular focus on allowing me to focus more on styling and optimising the timing/trajectories of individual segments?

Another example of types of animations which I'd love to be able to create in a simple way are [Animated Mathematica Functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/flash/). Apart from the fact that they're animating text, in overall style they're very similar to the above animations. They also raise the question of how to deal with text in a convenient way, for example when you want to "duplicate" part of a string, like when the `a`, `b`, `c`, `x` are "pulled out" of the function call in the `Append` animation.

(If the consensus of the answer turns out to be "Mathematica isn't the perfect tool for this", I'd be happy to hear about alternatives in answers or comments, but I'm sure it must be possible to get some decent results with Mathematica.)

Comment: In the usual animation and video tools (e.g. after effects) one often works with so-called keyframes. Parameters such as color, position and transparency of different objects are specified at discrete points in time (that can be moved along a time line). Usually one specifies everything as sequence of keyframes and appropriate interpolation (maybe with fancy fade-in/fade-out effects or polynomial paths etc.). Maybe this way of structuring animations can be applied here as well.

Comment: What Sascha said. If I was tasked with creating an animation as above, I would split it up into continuous segments that are easily parametrized, getting a list of functions `g[1][t], g[2][t], ...` then roll `gfinal[t_]:=Piecewise[{{g[1][t-0],t<1},{g[2][t-1],t<2},{g[3][t-2],t<3}...}]`. The code would be a bit cumbersome, but a lot would be copy and paste, so not too much toll on the programmer.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP That still requires you to match up all the positions (and other configurations) of all objects between `g[i][t]` and `g[i+1][t]` at the `t` where you switch from one to the next. Which is basically the same problem as I have above, just with more consistent notation throughout the animation. Sascha has a point with the keyframes though, so I guess one might be able to take a hybrid approach where you specify a list of object, and each object is represented as a list of keyframes where interpolation happens semi-automagically.

Comment: Well let's take your example, the first three keyframes are 1) a point (or line with length 0), 2) a line pointing at 0 rad, 3) a line pointing at 2Pi rad. With a bit of meta-programming, it's possible to generate code for the next keyframe by doing something along the lines of `g[2][t] = (Unevaluated[g[1][t]] /. SubValues[g] /. t->1 /. Line[{_,{1,0}}] -> Line[{{0,0},{Cos[2 Pi t, Sin[2 Pi t]}}])`. I realize, the comment section may be too small for this to be entirely clear and I should post an answer/extended comment, but I'm a bit constrained on time right now.

Comment: As someone who has worked with animation software before: The real point of having keyframes is not really to define every single step as a keyframe micromanaging all the information but to define some start and end keyframe carrying different information with regard to one or more parameters (such as size and rotation) and choosing an interpolation method/path **per parameter** for generating new in-between keyframes (that may or may not be exposed as editable keyframes themselves).

Comment: Addendum: To get a smooth, even animation the actual interpolation between keyframes is handled globally to archive a constant frame rate. I think Mathematica is a good tool to implement all this because it can handle **(1.)** a custom datatype `keyframe`, maybe using UpValues, **(2.)** mathematical description of interpolation between keyframes **(3.)** rendering the interpolated keyframe-sequences as vector- or raster-images.

Comment: @Sascha I'm not sure if we're speaking the same language or not here (you apparently have a deeper understanding of the problem, while I'm just an amateur taking a stab), so I hope you'll have a look at my extended comment below. What I defined as a keyframe, is the discontinuity points - one moment the line is getting longer, the next it's rotating, but I imagine, it's up to the programmer to mathematically define the function between one keyframe and another. Am I grasping the concept correctly, or is my understanding flawed?

Comment: Although the topic is interesting, I think the degree of generality you seem to be looking for is not very suitable for the Q&A format on this site. Aren't you essentially asking for a kind of analogue to Flash (keyframes, tweening, etc)? To do that in complete generality would require anticipating all the possible types of objects you're planning to animate, including images, text and vector graphics in 2D or 3D.

Comment: @Jens I agree that it's quite a broad question, but I got the impression that this particular SE is comparably open to those. Also, I'm not asking for someone to reimplement a Flash-like framework in the answers, but more about general techniques to make my life easier when creating these animations. If there's already such a package out there that would be a good answer, or if someone could point out some basic tips on how to improve the process for my example above. I'm not expecting answers to address all sorts of 2D and 3D animations. But I'm sure some simple tips are generally applicable.

Comment: Is the goal that you want to export the animation, or does it stay inside a *Mathematica* notebook? A simple approach would be to export a suitable `Manipulate` autorun sequence.

Comment: @Jens Ideally I want to be able to export the animation.

Comment: Then I would strongly recommend [this approach](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/86994). I think it can be adapted to a very broad range of animations.

Answer (score 14):

If you have recurring requirements, such as stringing together multiple animation segments in sequence, it makes sense to write some helper code to deal with things like timekeeping. You can decide what would be a convenient syntax to describe such an animation, then create functions to convert the convenient syntax to the required graphics expressions.

For example consider an animation that shows a point moving from 0 to 10 along the x axis, taking 5 seconds to do so. It then stays put for 2 seconds before returning to 0, taking 3 seconds. Suppose this could be represented as:

```
anim[Point[{x, 0}], {{x -> {0, 10}, 5}, 2, {x -> {10, 0}, 3}}]
```

The first argument is just a graphics expression with one or more symbolic parameters. The second argument is a "plan" for the animation describing how those parameters change over time. Some straightforward processing can analyse the duration of each step and work out how to set the parameter values as a function of time. My attempt at implementing this sort of approach is below. The general aim is to remove the distracting timeline accounting away from the graphics expressions, allowing you to focus on the content and styling of the animation. Eventually you might extend the syntax to add more features or handle more complex sequencing.

### A simplish implementation

First the code. I won't try to explain it in detail. Much of it is concerned with handling the multiple variations of the "plan" syntax (described below).

```
(* timestep processing *)
spat = (_Rule | _Symbol | _String);
expandStep[t_?NumericQ] := {Null, t}
expandStep[x : spat] := {x, 1}
expandStep[{x : spat ..}] := {x, 1}
expandStep[{x : spat .., t_?NumericQ}] := {x, t}

(* expand out simultaneous steps *)
fullsteps[{x__, t_List}] := {#, t} & /@ {x}

(* create animation function *)
anim[gr_, plan_] := Module[{p, gsyms, psyms, syms, tmax},
  p = expandStep /@ plan;
  gsyms = Cases[gr, obj[s_, _] :> s, -1];
  psyms = Cases[p, HoldPattern[s_ -> _] :> s, 2];
  syms = Union@Join[psyms, gsyms];
  p = Prepend[p, Append[Thread[syms -> 0], 0]];
  p[[All, -1]] = sf@p;
  p = Join @@ fullsteps /@ p;
  tmax = p[[-1, -1, 2]];
  With[{pl = p}, {Function[{t}, gr /. Association[clock[t] /@ pl]], tmax}]]

(* list of {start,finish} times for each part *)
sf[x_] := Partition[Accumulate[Last /@ x], 2, 1, {2, 2}, 0]

(* create parameter setting rules from global clock t *)
clock[t_][{_, {st_, _}}] /; t < st := Nothing
clock[t_][{Null, _}] := Nothing
clock[t_][{s_ -> {a_, b_}, {st_, fi_}}] := s -> a + (b - a) Clip[(t - st)/(fi - st), {0, 1}]
clock[t_][{s_ -> {a_, b_}, {fi_, fi_}}] := s -> b
clock[t_][{s_ -> a_, _}] := s -> a
clock[t_][{s : (_Symbol | _String), _}] := s -> 1

(* object appear/vanish/fade *)
SetAttributes[obj, HoldRest]
obj[0, _] := {}
obj[1, x_] := x
obj[r_Real, x_] := Style[x, Opacity[r]]
```

### Usage

The animation "plan" is a list of steps corresponding to consecutive time segments. Allowed steps are:

- `x` (symbol or string)  parameter $x$ is set to 1 (e.g. to make an
  `obj` appear - see below)
- `x -> a`  parameter $x$ is set to $a$
- `x -> {a, b}`  parameter $x$ runs from $a$ to $b$
- `{step1, step2, ...}` multiple of the above steps occur simultaneously in the same
  time segment
- `{step(s), t}`  the time segment duration is $t$
- `t` (numeric)  pause, i.e. nothing happens for time $t$

The default for $t$ if omitted in any step is $t=1$

The first argument of `anim` can contain ordinary graphics objects or special named objects:

- `obj[name, contents]` is a function which evaluates to `contents` if `name` is 1 and an empty list if `name` is 0. This allows for objects to appear and disappear as the animation progresses, by changing the parameter `name` between 1 and 0.

`anim` returns a list `{func, tmax}` where `tmax` is the total duration of the animation and `func[t]` returns the appropriate graphics expression for time `t`.

### Example

I suspect an example will be easier to follow than my explanation. Hopefully it is clear how each step of the animation "plan" plays out in the gif.

```
{f, tmax} = anim[{
    Darker@Green,
    obj["circle", {Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {0, θ}], 
                   Line[{{1, 0}, {0, 0}, {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}}],
                   Disk[{0, 0}, 0.2, {0, θ}]}],
    Pink,
    obj["label", Text[ToString[r, StandardForm] <> " rad", {0, y}]]},
   {
    {"circle", θ -> {0, 1}},
    {r -> 1, y -> -0.2, "label" -> {0, 1}, 0.5},
    0.5,
    θ -> {1, 2}, r -> 2,
    θ -> {2, 3}, r -> 3,
    θ -> {3, Pi}, r -> Pi,
    {y -> {-0.2, 0.4}, θ -> {Pi, 2 Pi}},
    r -> 2 Pi
    }];

Animate[Graphics[f[t], PlotRange -> 1.2, BaseStyle -> 16], 
  {t, 0, tmax},  AnimationRate -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! I didn't fully comprehend all of the code yet, but the general approach is very appealing. +1 PS you've got a typo in the golden ratio ;-)

Comment: @LLlAMnYP, thanks. I think the code is confusing too! I had the idea to use an association so that chunks of graphics could be named, which then drove the whole thing in a weird direction. I have a much better version now which I'll try to post later.

Answer (score 11):

This answer is growing bit by bit, though I won't be aiming to reproduce the first animation in OP in its entirety. I am, in fact, addressing just one or two aspects of the problem.

As a follow-up to my comment, I found this quite fast to write, so here it is.

```
Clear[g]
g[1, t_] = 
  Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {t, 0}}]}, PlotRange -> 1.1, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> {300, 300}];
g[2, t_] = 
  Unevaluated[g[1, t]] /. DownValues[g] /. t -> 1 /. 
   Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}] -> 
    Unevaluated[
     Sequence[Line[{{0, 0}, {Cos[2 Pi t], Sin[2 Pi t]}}], 
      Circle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 2 Pi t}]]];
g[3, t_] = 
  Unevaluated[g[2, t]] /. DownValues[g] /. t -> 1 /. 
   Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}] -> 
    Line[{{1 - Cos[Pi t/2], Sin[Pi t/2]}, {1, 0}}];
g[4, t_] = 
  Unevaluated[g[3, t]] /. DownValues[g] /. t -> 1 /. 
   Line[{{1, 1}, {1, 0}}] -> 
    Circle[{-Cot[t Pi/2], 0}, {Cot[t Pi/2] + 1, Cot[t Pi/2] + 1}, {0, 
      1/(Cot[t Pi/2] + 1)}];
gfull[t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{g[1, t], t < 1}, {g[2, t - 1], t < 2}, {g[3, t - 2], 
    t < 3}, {g[4, t - 3], t <= 4}}]
```

Re: the problem of tweaking timing, I figured, that each phase may as well have the same duration, and an additional function can fix this. For my example, I find the line rotates through a circle a bit too fast, and I'd like it to pause for a moment at the end when playing this with `Animate`. Instead of recoding the graphics, I just roll a custom function to pass to `gfull` instead of simply `t` *fixed, as compared to version from 16.03.16*:

```
phaseDurations = {.2, 1, 3, 1, 1, .2};
timing = Interpolation[
{{0}~Join~Accumulate[phaseDurations],
({0}~Join~Range[0,#]~Join~{#}&)[Length[phaseDurations]-2]}//Transpose,
InterpolationOrder -> 1]
Animate[gfull[timing[t]], {t,0,Total[phaseDurations]}]
```

Re: problem of both prettyfying things and working in local coordinate systems. Roll your own "primitives"! The code above may have nice functionality, but lets add a little more. I'm thinking, the `Graphics` should be organized something like `Graphics[{{primitives and directives 1}, {prims+dirs 2},...}, Options]` so I'll define a custom line like so:

```
myLine[origin_, length_, angle_] := With[
  {p1 = origin, p2 = origin + length {Cos[angle], Sin[angle]}},
  {Red, PointSize[.02], Point[{p1,p2}], Thick, Line[{p1,p2}]}]
```

Then I do the previous code again

```
Clear[g]
Block[{Graphics, myLine},
 g[1, t_] = Graphics[{myLine[{0, 0}, t, 0]},
              PlotRange -> 1.1, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> {300, 300}];

 g[2, t_] = 
  Unevaluated[g[1, t]] /. DownValues[g] /. t -> 1 /. myLine[{0, 0}, 1, 0] ->
    Unevaluated[Sequence[myLine[{0, 0}, 1, 2 Pi t],
        {Thick, Blue, Circle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 2 Pi t}]}]];

 g[3, t_] = 
  Unevaluated[g[2, t]] /. DownValues[g] /. t -> 1 /. 
   myLine[{0, 0}, 1, 2 Pi] -> myLine[{1, 0}, 1, Pi (1 - t/2)];

 g[4, t_] = 
  Unevaluated[g[3, t]] /. DownValues[g] /. t -> 1 /. 
   myLine[{1, 0}, 1, Pi/2] -> 
    Circle[{-Cot[t Pi/2], 0}, {Cot[t Pi/2] + 1, Cot[t Pi/2] + 1},
      {0, 1/(Cot[t Pi/2] + 1)}];
 ]

gfull[t_] = 
  Piecewise[{{g[1, t], t < 1}, {g[2, t - 1], t < 2}, {g[3, t - 2], 
     t < 3}, {g[4, t - 3], t <= 4}}];
```

Note the `Block` - I don't want premature evaluation to mess up my replacement rules. Finally, export to gif at 25 fps, thinking of `phaseDurations` as the timing of each phase in seconds.

```
Export["test.gif", 
 gfull[timing[#]] & /@ Range[0, Total@phaseDurations, 0.04], 
 "DisplayDurations" -> 
  ConstantArray[0.04, Round[Total@phaseDurations/0.04] + 1]]
```

[image: animation]

Of course, the primitive is not universal - the prettyfied line cannot transform into an arc. Also it briefly flashes red with an error message, as MMA tries to render an arc of fixed length, but infinite radius. But that's just a few more lines of code away. By granularizing all these steps it should be rather easy to create many custom objects, such as that text that has a time-dependent fade, e.g.

```
fadeText[text_, coords_, t0_, t_] = {Opacity[1 - Exp[-t/t0]], Text[text, coords]}
```

and at the same time, it will not need a separate hard-coded time slot. For instance, if the main processes in a given phase of the animation last for about 5 seconds, but the text should fade in within half a second, you don't need a 0.5 second sequence with `fadeText` and then 4.5 seconds with normal `Text`. Just use `fadeText[text,coords,.5,t]` and allow it to exist for the entire 5 seconds. It will be completely opaque anyway.