# How to divide the wine into two equal portions?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, puzzle

There is a 8-liter bottle is full of wine. There are two empty bottles that have capacity 5-liters and 3-liters. How can these three bottles be used to separate the wine into two 4-liter portions?

[image]

This is my current method:

```
a = Range[0, 8];
b = Range[0, 5];
c = Range[0, 3];
list = Select[Tuples[{a, b, c}], Total[#] == 8 &];

SetAttributes[CirclePlus, HoldFirst]
CirclePlus[l_[[a_]], b_] := 
 Module[{temp = l}, temp[[a]] = temp[[a]] + b; temp]

g = RelationGraph[
  Or @@ Table[(#1[[1]]⊕-a)[[2]]⊕a === #2, {a, 5}] || 
    Or @@ Table[(#1[[1]]⊕-a)[[3]]⊕a === #2, {a, 3}] || 
    Or @@ Table[(#1[[2]]⊕-a)[[3]]⊕a === #2, {a, 3}] || 
    Or @@ Table[(#1[[2]]⊕-a)[[1]]⊕a === #2, {a, 5}] || 
    Or @@ Table[(#1[[3]]⊕-a)[[1]]⊕a === #2, {a, 3}] || 
    Or @@ Table[(#1[[3]]⊕-a)[[2]]⊕a === #2, {a, 3}] &, list]
```

But I get a wrong answer.

```
FindShortestPath[g, {8, 0, 0}, {4, 4, 0}]
```

> `{{8, 0, 0}, {4, 4, 0}}`

Actually the answer is

> `{8,0,0}->{3,5,0}->{3,2,3}->{6,2,0}->{6,0,2}->{1,5,2}->{1,4,3}->{4,4,0}`

How can I use *Mathematica* to solve this problem?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

How about:

```
list = Select[Tuples@Range[0, {8, 5, 3}], Total[#] == 8 &];

f[x_, y_] := Count[y ({8, 5, 3} - y) (x - y), 0] >= 2

sp = FindShortestPath[RelationGraph[f, list], {8, 0, 0}, {4, 4, 0}]
(* {{8, 0, 0}, {3, 5, 0}, {3, 2, 3}, {6, 2, 0}, {6, 0, 2}, {1, 5, 2}, {1, 4, 3}, {4, 4, 0}} *)
```

**Explanation for `f`**

- The transfer is from one bottle to one other, therefore the uninvolved bottle does not change - so $(y - x)$ must contain a zero for that bottle.
- The transfer must either empty the source bottle (in which case there is a zero in $y$) or fill the destination bottle (in which case there is a zero in $(\{8, 5, 3\} - y)$
- So overall the product $y(\{8, 5, 3\} - y) (y-x)$ must contain at least two zeros for a valid step.

**Gratuitous animation**

[image]

To make the animation I used the animation sequencing code from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110558/862) and:

```
rules = MapThread[Thread[{a, b, c} -> Transpose@{#1, #2}] &,
    {Most@sp, Rest@sp}] ~Riffle~ 0.5 ~Append~ 1;

grfx = {EdgeForm[Blue], FaceForm[],
   Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 8}], Rectangle[{2, 0}, {3, 5}], Rectangle[{4, 0}, {5, 3}],
   FaceForm[Red],
   Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, a}], Rectangle[{2, 0}, {3, b}], Rectangle[{4, 0}, {5, c}]};

{fn, tmax} = anim[grfx, rules];
Animate[Graphics[fn[t]], {t, 0, tmax}]
```

---

Those without [`RelationGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html) may use:

```
g = Graph[ Rule @@@ Pick[#, f @@@ #] & @ Permutations[list, {2}] ];

FindShortestPath[g, {8, 0, 0}, {4, 4, 0}]
```

Comment: I cannot understand your `f`

Comment: @yode, I added some explanation

Comment: I have to say this is a wonderful answer.

Comment: @SimonWoods Nice one (+1). Personally, I would have done [`JohnMcClane[{8, 5, 3}, {4, 4, 0}]`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_MoNu9Mkm4).

Comment: @SimonWoods wonderful and neat animation :)

Comment: @Xavier I think it would be `ZeusCarver[...]`  or both :)

Comment: I like your animation,Can you share your code?:)

Comment: It's not gratuitous if it lends an excellent intuitive understanding of the solution!

Comment: Please show the code for the animation. It's so amazing! :)

Comment: @iFikr I added the animation code.

Comment: @SimonWoods Nice, I never regret using Mathematica and being amazed by its capabilities on daily basis.